# Determining if $aRb \iff \exists c\in N: a = b +c$ defines an equivalence relationship

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> A binary relation $R$ on $N$ is defined by the following rule:
>
> $$aRb \Leftrightarrow \exists c\in N: a = b +c$$
>
> Prove whether or not it is an equivalence relation.

I'm not sure if what I've done is correct, but this is what I have.

$\text{Reflexivity}:$ $\forall a\in \mathbb{N}: aRa$

$ aRa \Leftrightarrow \exists c\in N: a = a +c \hspace{1cm}\therefore  \text{reflexive}$

$\text{Symmertric}:$ $\forall a,b\in \mathbb{N}: aRb \implies bRa$

$ aRb \Leftrightarrow \exists c\in N: a = b +c \hspace{1cm}bRa \Leftrightarrow \exists c\in N: b = a +c \hspace{1cm}\therefore  \text{not symmetric}$

$\text{Transitive}:$ $\forall a,b,d\in \mathbb{N}: aRb \wedge bRd \implies aRd$

$ (\exists c\in N: a = b +c) \wedge (\exists c\in N: b = d +c) \Leftrightarrow (\exists c\in N: a = d +c)\hspace{1cm}\therefore  \text{transitive}$

Comment: Just provide an example showing that symmetric property does not hold. For example, $3R1$ holds but $1R3$ does not.

Comment: Oh right, that's a lot easier than what I was doing. Is the proof as a whole correct?

Comment: Um, you didn't do *anything* so far as I can tell.  You gave the definition and then stated (correctly, I'll admit) whether the relationship followed it.  But you didn't ever explain *why* or how you came up with the answer.  Also for transitive you use the variable c for two different numbers.

Comment: Providing an example showing that one of the three properties fails to hold (in this case we did it the symmetric property) is enough to show that $R$ is not an equivalence relation. Actually, verifying the reflexive and transitive properties are useless.

Comment: @fleablood: For symmetric I thought if we have $a = b + c$ and $b = a + c$, it would follow that one couldn't imply the other?

Comment: @fleablood: Good call regrading transitive definition

Comment: Your definition of symmetry is fine but, again, I don't see any proof or work going on at all.  You are simply saying "this is true" "this isn't true".  I haven't seen you *do* anything.